# Algolia calendar widget?

Tags: algolia

the algolia tourism demo shows a calendar selector similar to airbnb.

https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/examples/tourism/

Is there a specific formatting required for that to work? I cannot find documentation regarding this widget.

Answer (score 0):

This demo displays calendar inputs but actually doesn't use them (disabled). They are just there for the demo purpose.

Since the calendar widget is not part of the default widgets, maybe you can give a try to a custom widget like they did in [this comment](https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch.js/issues/1077#issuecomment-225200518).

Comment: thanks. that github comment is partially helpful but ignores multiple blocked  dates and overlapping dates which is pretty basic functionality for a calendar. Leaving this open for a little longer to see if someone else has found a community solution that works.